# cannot play sound using QMediaPlayer

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyqt6

I am going to create a piano app, the sound is played by `QMediaPlayer`, the problem is there is no spund when pressing keys like `q` and `w`, so what's wrong ?

I had thought it might be the players made from  `QMediaPlayer` are garbage-collected, but I had sotred them into the values of `self.keyText2player`, so I think this is not the cause.

```
import sys,os

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QAudioOutput
from PyQt6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # Permissions QFile::​permissions() const

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.keyTextList=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', ',']
        self.keyText2player={}


        self.unfinishedDir=r'C:\Users\22815\Downloads\Real Guitar - Music Band Game_3.39.1_Apkpure\assets\sfx\distortion'
        self.toneFilePathList=['1.ogg', '2.ogg', '3.ogg', '4.ogg', '5.ogg', '6.ogg', '7.ogg', '8.ogg', '9.ogg', '10.ogg', '11.ogg', '12.ogg', '13.ogg', '14.ogg', '15.ogg', '16.ogg', '17.ogg', '18.ogg', '19.ogg', '20.ogg', '21.ogg', '22.ogg', '23.ogg', '24.ogg', '25.ogg', '26.ogg', '27.ogg', '28.ogg', '29.ogg', '30.ogg', '31.ogg', '32.ogg', '33.ogg', '34.ogg', '35.ogg', '36.ogg', '37.ogg', '38.ogg', '39.ogg', '40.ogg', '41.ogg', '42.ogg', '43.ogg', '44.ogg']
        for index,keyText in enumerate(self.keyTextList):
            self.keyText2player[keyText]=self.createMediaPlayer(os.path.join(self.unfinishedDir,self.toneFilePathList[index])) 
        
        # print(self.toneFilePathList)
        
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print(self.keyText2player[event.text()])
        self.keyText2player[event.text()].play()

        return super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def onMediaStateChanged(self, status):
        print(status)



    def createMediaPlayer(self,filePath):
        print(filePath)
        player = QMediaPlayer()
        audioOutput = QAudioOutput()
        player.setAudioOutput(audioOutput)
        player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filePath))
        audioOutput.setVolume(100)
        player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.onMediaStateChanged)
        return player



def main():
    import sys


    # QGuiApplication.setFont()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    trayIcon = MainWindow()
    trayIcon.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Using QMediaPlayer for this purpose is not very effective, and using unique players for each note is certainly *not* a good approach. At least, consider using [QSoundEffect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsoundeffect.html).

Comment: @musicamante Thanks so much! I changed `QMediaPlayer` to `QSoundEffect` in the above code, it works ! BTW, is using unique QSoundEffect instance for each note a good approach?